# Docker socket permissions within container

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm trying to access docker running on my host from a user within a container. I'm attempting to do this by mapping the socket on my host to the container volume `docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock myimage bash`

on my host `ls -l` on /var/run/docker.sock shows that the owner is my normal host user (not root), but when I look in the container, it's owned by root. Consequently I get "permission denied" when trying to connect to docker within the container. Here is a sample image

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y python python-dev python3.6 python-pip 
virtualenv libssl-dev libpq-dev git build-essential libfontconfig1 
libfontconfig1-dev
RUN pip install setuptools docker


RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -d /usr/local/myuser myuser
RUN chown -R myuser: /usr/local/myuser
USER myuser
```

build the image

`docker build -t myimage .`

start a bash shell

`docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock myimage bash`

try for example to connect via python

```
python -c "import docker; c = docker.from_env(); c.containers.list()
```

gives a permission denied error.

How can I map the correct permissions of the volume (and why do they change when I map the volume)? And is it possible to do this in the Dockerfile or in the run command (eg my actual application is using docker-compose).

I've tried creating a docker group in my dockerfile and adding myuser to the group but this does not seem to work, i'm not sure why but possibly because I'm on a mac and installed docker using the gui installer

Answer (score 0):

Simple change UID of the user,

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -d /usr/local/myuser -u ${UID} myuser
```

where UID can be taken via

```
id
```

in terminal

Comment: still permission denied. socket is still owned by root in container and by my ${UID} on my host

Comment: it's look like python docker not working in macos, u can check it by running docker run  -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  ddmitrii/support curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json